# getimagesize($file['tmp_name'])=== false is not working in php 5.6

Tags: joomla-3.x, validation

I am using the below code to validate an image.

```
getimagesize($file['tmp_name'])=== false
```

It's working fine in php 5.2 (wamp server local), but not working in live website(php 5.6).

`MIME_Content_type` is showing that it's an `image/jpeg`, but it's not an image.

What should I do?

I am using joomla 3.10

Comment: Is this a Joomla-centric question?  It seems to be a matter of pure php.  Did you search Stackoverflow?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your error log? Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3121547/2943403 What is the file type being uploaded?  Please offer more details. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12761445/2943403

Comment: Are you referencing `$_FILES` with your `$file` variable? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755263/2943403

Comment: I need to check image before uploading in joomla. when i checked MIME TYPE it's showing image/jpeg but it's not an image. The audit team provided the image which mime type is image but it's a exe file.  Please suggest me what should i do...?

Comment: Which of these solutions have you tried so far?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/6755192/2943403  If you can solve your own question after researching and testing, please answer your own question and mark it with the green tick.

Comment: I am already checked above solution but its not working.. I  also tried list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file); if($width <= '0'){$app->enqueueMessage(\JText::sprintf('JLIB_MEDIA_ERROR_WARNINVALID_IMG', $mime), 'error');} its showing same value for valid image and invalid image

Comment: Please add those relevant details to your question so that the full story is all in one place.  (This also bumps your question to the top of the "active questions" list.)

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP documentation, `getimagesize()` should not be used to check if file is an image:

> This function expects filename to be a valid image file. If a
>   non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image
>   and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain
>   nonsensical values.
>
> Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image.
>   Use a purpose-built solution such as the [Fileinfo](https://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension instead.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: i got your point sir.. Can you suggest me any joomla or php function with the help of which i can findout the file content...